# How can i do to get all class of a given package with guava

Tags: java, reflection, package, guava

I am working on a maven project and I added to my pom.xml file the guava dependency and the dependency of an other project. I want to get all class of a given package of that project which I have added to my pom as a dependency.
So I tried with this :

```
public void getClassOfPackage() {

    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        for (final ClassPath.ClassInfo info : ClassPath.from(loader)
                .getTopLevelClasses()) {

                System.out.println(info.getSimpleName());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestMain().getClassOfPackage();
}
```

And I know that is wrong because it gives that in console:

```
HierarchicalConfigurationConverter
HierarchicalConfigurationXMLReader
HierarchicalINIConfiguration
SubsetConfiguration
SystemConfiguration...
```

I don't know where I can specify the project where I am talking about and how I can just pass the package name and it gives me all class which it contains.

Comment: What's your question, exactly? Are you asking how you can get the classes from the lines? Have you tried parsing them? It seems like you could split them along the `$` and whatever's on the right is your classname.

Comment: i have a package named org.mypackage where i have a lot of Entities so i want in the class above to pass juste the package name  "org.mypackage" and the programme show me all class name of that package

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you were asking. Could you put a sentence in at the end explaining that?

Comment: yes of course and it's done now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found tow solutions :

**With guava :**

```
public void getClassOfPackage(String packagenom) {

    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    try {

        ClassPath classpath = ClassPath.from(loader); // scans the class path used by classloader
        for (ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : classpath.getTopLevelClasses(packagenom)) {
         if(!classInfo.getSimpleName().endsWith("_")){
            System.out.println(classInfo.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestMain().getClassOfPackage("org.myproject");
}
```

**With Java.util:**

```
    public List<Class> getClassOfPackage(String packageName)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();

    assert classLoader != null;
    String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
    Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
    List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL resource = resources.nextElement();
        dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
    }
    ArrayList<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    for (File directory : dirs) {
        classes.addAll(findClasses(directory, packageName));
    }
    return classes;
}

private static List<Class> findClasses(File directory, String packageName)
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        return classes;
    }
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            assert !file.getName().contains(".");
            classes.addAll(findClasses(file,
                    packageName + "." + file.getName()));
        } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            classes.add(Class.forName(packageName
                    + '.'
                    + file.getName().substring(0,
                            file.getName().length() - 6)));
        }
    }
    return classes;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        IOException {

    for (Class className : new ClassOfPackage()
            .getClassOfPackage("org.mypackage")) {
        if (!className.getSimpleName().endsWith("_")) {
            System.out.println(className.getSimpleName());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem now is :  this don't work when i convert my class to a managedBean

Answer (score 2):

I can show all the classes whitch are in the same project but for an other project added as a dependency in pom.xml not yet :

The solution for what we i have in the same project:

```
 public void getClassOfPackage() {

    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    try {

        ClassPath classpath = ClassPath.from(loader); // scans the class path used by classloader
        for (ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : classpath.getTopLevelClasses("org.mypackage")) {
          System.out.println(classInfo.getSimpleName()+" <==> "+classInfo.getPackageName());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestMain().getClassOfPackage();
}
```

Comment: classpath.getTopLevelClasses("org.mypackage") will not work if it's a fat jar or a BOOT jar

Answer (score 1):

This is why you're seeing it print out `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`:

```
} else {
     System.out.println(loader.getClass().getName());
}
```

Every class on your classpath that isn't in your package is causing your program to print out the name of the `ClassLoader` implementation class, which you probably don't want.

Also, while `info.getName().startsWith("org.mypackage")` should work, it might be preferable to write `info.getPackageName().equals("org.mypackage")` (or `startsWith` if you want to include subpackages too).

Comment: @TinyOS: Your edit doesn't change anything about my answer, though I did edit it to try to make it more clear. I've explained why you're seeing the output you're seeing. Does making that change fix things for you?

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to solve this problem with the help of [Google reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/).

Please check the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection) for the correct answer - **note that the checked answer does not provide a working solution, the second one (Aleksander Blomskøld) does!**

Comment: i try juste with guava and it works , you can see my answer bellow but the problem now is : how to show all classes of a given package in other project whitch added to the current application by maven dependencies :

More details:

I have my main maven project where i want to show all classes of an other project nammed services. and i have the dependency of services project in the pom of my main project . I hope that my issue is clear for you now